# React-Native draggable list view like trello board

Tags: react-native, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am developing the application where I need the draggable items between two list and just like the Trello board.

I found the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-board but unfortunately, this library is not working as they are using the deprecated listview and the library is very old I can't update myself this library.

Please let me know any solution that work for my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Library suggestions are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Okay I'll update the question

Comment: Hi @ZeeshanAnsari , did you find a solution ? I might be in the same situation.